# What is a multi-standard mcu?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems, wireless-communication

I was watching a video on the ti products out currently for wireless microcontrollers, and they mentioned a "multi-standard" CC2650 mcu here http://bcove.me/uekqgi7q. What makes a microcontroller "multi-standard"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "multi-standard" for CC2650 that the microcontroller support, BLE, Zigbee, 6lowpan, and RF4CE. It is the same SOC, and you load different software stacks support different wireless protocols.

Comment: So in extension of this idea, is a standard then BLE, Zigbee, or 6lowpan on its own (like a communication standard)?

Comment: Yes, BLE, Zigbee, and 6lowpan can or does communicate in 2.4GHz frequency.

Comment: But is communication in the 2.4GHz range what makes it a "standard"? <- more of my question

Comment: I think the standards referred to are BLE, Zigbee, 6Lowpan etc. This are industry standards